# How do I send data with accurate timing in Android app?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timing

I have a scenario where I have some timing data that I get from a MIDI file. When a MIDI note needs to be played, I need to send a command over UDP. Basically, I have instructions that say "play note A, wait 125ms, play note B, wait 300ms, play note C..." and each time I "play note X" I need to send data over UDP. I have tried using both a TimerTask and a simple thread with a loop that check the system time and calculate how much time has elapsed and decide whether or not to play a note based on that, but both methods seem to have timing issues. The TimerTask doesn't run exactly on the specified interval (which was stated in the documentation) so I get erratic messages. The thread works better, but it still hiccups sometimes which I assume is because other threads are getting priority over it.

Is there a better way to send this data with more accurate timing? Is there something I can use like the Clip interface in Java that is used for playing audio?

Any assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach just about doomed to failure.  Let me count the issues here:

1)Android is not a real time OS.  Neither is Linux (which its built on).  Expecting ms level timings to happen exactly correctly is never going to work.  Even if the clock is accurate enough to interrupt on a 1ms rate, there's no assurance that Linux will schedule your thread for wakeup.

2)TimerTasks aren't promised to be accurate even to the degree limited by 1.

3)You're then sending it somewhere via UDP?  A protocol that has no assurance as to delivery or timing, to a receiver who will then do something with it-  and that receiver may have additional timing issues of its own.

Throw out this entire approach and start over would be my advice.  Every single step of this says bad idea.

Comment: So how does an application that plays audio keep proper time? When an Android app plays a song from a file it doesn't have these types of issues. I'm not saying you aren't correct above, I just want to know how audio playback is accomplished despite the issues you mentioned

Comment: Not by timing data.  It writes the file data to memory.  Then it tells the sound card where the data is, and the sound card reads the memory and handles outputting it.  This is a simplification of course (the full answer involves things like DMA and buffer recycling), but to play actual music it hands it off to a separate piece of hardware.